# Getting form errors in form collections inside a controller Symfony 2

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have the following code in my controller.

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $entity = $em->getRepository('CIInventoryBundle:DiscountLevelItem')->find($discountLevelItemId);
    $form = $this->createForm(new DiscountLevelItemCollectionType(), $entity);
    $form->bindRequest($request);

    $errors = array();
    foreach ($form['discountLevelItemProducts'] as $formField) {
        $errors[] = $formField->getErrors();
    }
    var_dump($errors);
    die;

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        //remove items without discount type
        foreach ($entity->getDiscountLevelItemProducts() as $item) {
            if (!$item->getDiscountType()) {
                $entity->getDiscountLevelItemProducts()->removeElement($item);
                $em->remove($item);
            }
        }

        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

        $responseData = array(
            'status' => 'success',
            'message' => 'Supplier product discounts successfully saved.'
        );
    } else {
        $responseData = array(
            'status' => 'error',
            'form' => $this-        >renderView('CIInventoryBundle:DiscountLevel:manageProducts.html.twig', array(
                'entity' => $entity,
                'form' => $form->createView()
            ))
        );
    }
    return new Response(json_encode($responseData), 200, array('Content-Type'=>'application/json'));
```

I submitted the following data:

> ci_inventorybundle_discountlevelitemcollectiontype[_token]:17044e40450d5546f4be40e6fbe28f2866dffcfb
>   ci_inventorybundle_discountlevelitemcollectiontype[discountLevelItemProducts][2][trucking]:0.00
>   ci_inventorybundle_discountlevelitemcollectiontype[discountLevelItemProducts][2][discountValue]:0.00
>   ci_inventorybundle_discountlevelitemcollectiontype[discountLevelItemProducts][2][discountType]:Fixed
>   ci_inventorybundle_discountlevelitemcollectiontype[discountLevelItemProducts][2][variant]:1567

when I try to var_dump the $errors i array i got the following:

```
 array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  [1]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

I am using Symfony 2.0.23.

My question is how can i get the form errors of form collections programmatically?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can take [getErrorsAsString](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.php#L849) method as an example to get the functionality you want. Also you have to set `invalid_message` option on the form field to change `This value is invalid` message.